# Why does a total solar eclipse happen every 18 Months?

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy, planets, solar-system, eclipse

What is the math involved in calculating how often a total solar eclipse happens. Can you predict it by just looking at the period of the moon around the earth and the period of the earth around the sun?

Edit: I am not asking why it doesn't happen more often but the minimum information you would need to determine it happens every 18 months. Can you predict this using just the period of the moon and the earth, or do you need to know more information?

Comment: Well the moons orbit is tilted with respect to the earths orbital plane about the sun, that kinda answers your unasked question about why they don't happen more often, but also speaks to why you can't simply just look at the orbital periods.